# Get user private channel list using Twilio Programmable Chat REST API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Using a Twilio user identity, which API(s) can I call to retrieve the list of **private** channels this user is member of?

Comment: Is this via the JavaScript SDK on the client side or the REST API? What have you tried so far? Can you share the code you have to this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash) comment rang a bell, so we found this:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/api/user-channels

```
GET /Services/{Instance SID}/Users/{User SID}/Channels
```